# How to connect to Salesforce using Talend?

Tags: talend

I'm new with Talend and can't seem to figure out how to connect to Salesforce using Talend and get all objects.  Once all objects are listed how to import specific object data to a Sql Server?

NOTE:  We get a new token every time we connect to the Salesforce site.
Does anyone have a job similar to my scenario who can post for reference?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the tutorial in the following link. You need to setup the salesforce connection in your Talend repository and it will list all the salesforce entities.

[Salesforce Connection](https://help.talend.com/reader/eT1URirEr8V_hj9ytQOHvQ/0g~D73cIPhVvDDY13HQVTQ)

Then you can use the tSalesforceInput component to retrieve specific entities:

[tSalesforceInput](https://help.talend.com/reader/iYcvdknuprDzYycT3WRU8w/Tdf_WzwhVSkZ_OwYctAekg)